# Azure new users: You do not have permission to view this directory or page

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have a web app in Azure. The access to that web app is controlled by Azure Active Directory. The app is up and running since September of last year. I didn't make any changes to the app for a while and have 33 users in that app.
So, a week ago I tried to add a user, using the same methods and paths I used before.
The new user can log in to microsoft (portal.office.com). After the initial log in and changing of the password the user goes to the web app in Azure and get the following error: **You do not have permission to view this directory or page**.
Error tracing gives me this:

> HTTP Error 401.73 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page.
>
> Most likely causes: The authenticated user does not have access to a
>   resource needed to process the request.
>
> Things you can try: Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for
>   this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing
>   rule for failed requests, click here.
>
> Detailed Error Information: Module       EasyAuthModule_32bit
>   Notification     BeginRequest Handler
>   ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 Error Code    0x80004005
>   Requested URL    https://*******:80/.auth/login/aad/callback Physical
>   Path     D:\home\site\wwwroot.auth\login\aad\callback Logon Method
>   Not yet determined Logon User    Not yet determined
>
> More Information: This is the generic Access Denied error returned by
>   IIS. Typically, there is a substatus code associated with this error
>   that describes why the server denied the request. Check the IIS Log
>   file to determine whether a substatus code is associated with this
>   failure. View more information »
>
> Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

Another observed behavior: usually when new users are logging in the web app asks for permissions for the AD to access their account information. Ever since this problem came up this is not the case any more.

Other users do not have any problems logging in. This problem only happens with new users who never logged in before.

EDIT: When I go to Active Directory and look at sign ins, I see failures to log into the web app with sign-in error code **90092**. Failure Reason: **Other**.
Microsoft help desk could not give me details on that error code.

Comment: Try asking the new user to open the app in an incognito/private browser session and let me know the outcome. This 401.73 is Azure EasyAuth specific

Comment: Tried to log in in Private mode and it didn't help. Used different browsers, still doesn't work.

Comment: Based on your description, I just created an new AAD app to check this issue. When logging, the consent window could pop up and I could successfully access my web app using App Service AAD authentication. I would recommend you try to Grant Permissions for your AAD app to narrow this issue. Details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications#updating-an-application).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the related question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582510/azure-ad-prompt-user-admin-to-re-consent-after-changing-application-permissions). All new users have to first **consent** the application (agree and give your application permissions to access their profile / or you indicated as required permissions).

In short, you have to design "sign-up" button for your application, which uses the "login_url" and appends "&prompt=consent" to the query string.

Read [all related resources here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-dev-consent-framework) to better understand the consent framework.

And please read the documentation about [Azure App Service Authentication/Authorization here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview), as well as the [Azure AD specific documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I just found an answer. I created a test app and set it up to mirror the settings of my live app.
In Required Permissions the new app had nothing for Microsoft Graph, the live app had 5 permissions. I deleted Microsoft Graph and it works now!

I wish Microsoft communicated better about discontinued API's. I did get an alert, but it was mostly talking about MS Office 365.